# What is a better way to go for a simple file upload and download: NSURLConnection or ASIHTTP?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

I want to include simple file uploading and downloading [any type of file e.g. .pdf, .pptx ,.txt etc] functionality in my application.

What is the better way to opt for using asihttp or NSURLConnection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our team is using AsiHttp now, it supports more important functionality like synchronous and asynchronous request, better support for some network activity

[AsiHttp](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)